# Send mail in laravel by using klaviyo but got 'error (403) You must specify an API key to make requests.'

Tags: laravel, klaviyo

```
public function forgetPassword(Request $request){
  try{  
                       $klaviyoResponse = Http::withHeaders([
                            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $klaviyoApiKey,
                            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                        ])->post('https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v1/email-template/send', [
                            'email' => $recipientEmail,
                            'template_id' => $templateId,
                            'context' => [
                                'reset_link' => $resetLink,
                                'token' => $token
                            ],
                        ]); 
    }catch(Exception $e){
                return response()->json(['status'=>false,'message' =>$e->getMessage()],400);
            }
        }
```

> Error:
> array:2 [
> "status" => 403
> "message" => "You must specify an API key to make requests."
> ]
>
> Help me to solve this Forbidden error i also follow the klaviyo documentation but still stucked.

Comment: The error message is descriptive. As it says, you have to add API key to the call you are trying to make. Maybe this link (https://developers.klaviyo.com/en/docs/retrieve_api_credentials) helps you.

Comment: from where you are retrieving the $klaviyoApiKey ?

Comment: Per [documentation](https://developers.klaviyo.com/en/reference/api_overview#private-key-authentication), server accepts `Authorization: Klaviyo-API-Key {your-private-api-key}` instead `Bearer` prefix.